# R - How to subset and sum over a dataframe with list of vectors that contain ids?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, subset, vectorization

I have a data frame as follows:

```
nearby_ids <- NULL

for (i in 1:10){
string <- paste(as.character(sample(setdiff(1:10,i), sample(setdiff(1:10,i)))), collapse = ",")
nearby_ids <- c(nearby_ids, string)}

my_df <- data.frame(school_id=1:10, classes=sample(1:50, 10), nearby_schools_id = nearby_ids, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

This is how it looks:

[image: dataframe resulted]

The variables "school_id" and "classes" are integers, and nearby_schools_id is character.

What I want is the following (hopefully without going through loops):

For each row, I want to take the nearby_schools_ids, use them as indices to subset the dataframe, and for that subsetted dataframe I want to sum over "classes".

The idea is, I want to know the total number of classes for all nearby schools.

**Expectation:**
So for row 1 for example, I want to output 122 (= 46+8+44+24).

I know I need to use `strsplit` here. But I'm trying to avoid looping and apply()ing (I have some 3 million rows, and I want the most efficient way possible).
Immediately when I implement `strsplit(my_df$nearby_schools_id, ",")` I get back a list of vectors, which is making things slightly more complicated to do.

Is there a vectorization solution for this?
What is the best way to solve it?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to @Ronak's logic, but the matching procedure can be done in bulk.
*Updated now to take account of empty list of nearby schools*

```
spl <- strsplit(my_df$nearby_schools_id, ",", fixed=TRUE)
sa <- seq_along(spl)
my_df$result <- tapply(
    my_df$classes[match(unlist(spl),my_df$school_id)],
    factor(rep(sa, lengths(spl)), levels=sa),
    FUN=sum
)
```

Testing on 3 million rows:

```
my_df <- my_df[rep(1:10,3e5),]
my_df$school_id <- 1:3e6

system.time({
spl <- strsplit(my_df$nearby_schools_id, ",", fixed=TRUE)
tapply(
    my_df$classes[match(unlist(spl),my_df$school_id)],
    rep(seq_along(spl), lengths(spl)),
    FUN=sum
)
})
##   user  system elapsed 
## 10.206   0.492  10.698
```

Comment: I think this is one can be very useful. But my ids are random and not sequential.
Is there a way to edit it your code in order to accommodate non-sequential "school_id"?

Comment: @Am95 - i think it should. I'm just looping over each row of the dataset and returning the sum for that row in order as shown in the dataset. Try scrambling the input like `my_df <- my_df[sample(nrow(my_df)),]` - it should still give the correct result.

Comment: Thanks a lot! this was great. I benchmarked this for each row on my data at 0.0000212 seconds! Excellent solution.

Comment: Ops! one more thing just came out. Some of my nearby_schools_id are empty (no nearby schools). But this is not showing in tapply output. So in the end I'm getting less than the number of rows in my data set (i.e. my_df).

Is there a way to fill in the missing values?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can actually do this without any kind of splitting. Try this approach :

```
my_df$result <- sapply(strsplit(my_df$nearby_schools_id, ','), function(x) 
                       sum(my_df$classes[as.numeric(x)]))
```

If your data is not sorted by school id's or if you don't have continuous sequence of id's you can use `match` to get the correct id's.

```
my_df$result <- sapply(strsplit(my_df$nearby_schools_id, ','), function(x)
                  sum(my_df$classes[match(as.numeric(x), my_df$school_id)]))
```

Comment: I see, thanks.

But using apply() with a "match()" and 3 million row is a killer! I benchmarked your method at 0.03732 seconds per row, which makes it about 31.1 hours of running time! 

Therefore, I'm looking for something more efficient :'(